Unpacking the last arguments with star spread operator in Groovy closure
Groovy can unpack lists or tuples with the spread operator (*), which looks like in Python.
In Python we can partially unpack a tuple, like this:
mytuple = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
first, *others = mytuple

print(repr(first))
# 'a'
print(repr(others))
# ['b', 'c', 'd']

I wish to unpack closure arguments in the same way in Groovy, would something similar to this be possible:
inputs = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
          ['A', 'B', 'C']]

inputs.each { first, *others -> // Invalid. Any alternative?
              println "first=$first others=${others.join(',')}" }

I found out about Variable length arguments, but they don't behave as the Python example:
inputs.each { first, String... others -> 
              println "first=$first others=${others.join(',')}" }

first=[a, b, c, d] others=[]
first=[A, B, C] others=[]


Groovy's destructuring game is rather weak-sauce.  But this will do inputs.each{ println "first=${it.first()} others=${it.tail().join(',')}" }

Here's another way to do it using destructuring assignments:
inputs.each {
   def (head, tail) = [it.first(), it.tail()]
   println( "first=${head}, others=${tail.join(','}" )
}

